# How to tell if one Div is to the right or left of another div? Jquery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Say that you have this:

```
<div id="1"></div><div id="2"></div><div id="3"></div>
```

Can you use Javascript/jQuery to find that id="2" is to the right of id="1"?

Comment: do you mean to the right as in displayed to the right, or to the right as in the next element?

Comment: Obviously he means "displayed". @TaylorMac why are you asking this, just for the fun of it or for a real purpose?

Comment: one question - are you asking this for the purposes of webdesign or is this issue something that you need to know once the DOM is complete (ie, for user interaction)?

Comment: Those IDs are invalid. They must start with a letter.

Comment: i don't think its obvious that he means display, as div's are block elements natively, and he's not provided us with css to prove that the are floated or set inline.  i think its more likely that he just wantes the previous elements id.

Comment: @nathan Yeah you're right, I was too presumptuous. Poorly worded question.

Comment: We need to know if you're talking about the order these elements appear in the HTML or the physical screen coordinates. The two approaches are quite different.

Comment: ok sorry the ID may very well be "div1" "div2". I need to be able to store (before: "div1" after: "div3") for "div2", or any other div as they appear in HTML

Comment: Then you should definitely check out Nathan's answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're looking for the div that comes before #2, do something like this:

```
$("#2").prev("div")
```

Comment: yes, see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/27zwz/.  prev() and next() traverse sibling dom elements.

Comment: don't forget to mark as answer if this is the solution to your problem

Comment: That will only determine their order in the DOM, which doesn't necessarily mean that they are displayed in that order.

Comment: @guffa, that is correct, but i confirmed with the op in the comments that is what he was looking for.  otherwise, your answer is awesome.

Comment: @Guffa I thought he literally meant left or right of each other - in a graphic sense. LOL

Comment: Yes sorry for the ambiguous question. I am floating all of the objects left, so the previous object in a parent div should always be the one displayed before it (to the left or above). I should have included that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but no, i don't think you can.

First off are you talking about in the code or how it comes out on the screen?  3 divs listed like will actually each show up on thier own lines.  You need to use spans to keep them all on the same line.

Comment: You are right. I just mean it's displayed before the other element

Comment: No, you don't need spans to keep them on the same line. You could for example apply the style `float:left;` to the divs to make them line up beside each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could get their positions, and if div#i1's position is lesser than the one of div#i2's position (their x positioning, if you will). http://api.jquery.com/position/

```
#Requires jQuery
var d1x = $('div#i1').position().left,
    d2x = $('div#i2').position().left;

$('span').html((d1x < d2x) ? "yes" : "no");
```

I don't think IDs can be solely numeric. It might work, but it's not a good practice.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PKpdp/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. How you check that depends on what you mean exactly by "to the right".

You can use the `offset` method to get the position of the two elements:

```
o1 = $('#1').offset();
o2 = $('#2').offset();
```

Now you can compare the `left` and `top` properties of the `o1` and `o2` objects.

If you by "to the right" mean that they are beside each other, and the second div is on the right side, you have to compare both properties:

```
if (o1.top == o2.top && o1.left < o2.left) ...
```

If you only mean that the second div should be more to the right than the first, then you only need to compare the `left` properties:

```
if (o1.left < o2.left) ...
```

Note that an `id` should not start with a digit. Using for example `id="x1"` and `id="x2"` would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
function is_div2_after_div1() {
  is_after = null;
  $("#parent > div").each(function(i, el) {
    if (is_after !== null) return;
    if (el.id && el.id == "div1") is_after = true;
    if (el.id && el.id == "div2") is_after = false;
  }
  return is_after;
}
```